# How to ensure I am buying an torx key for automotive repair?

Tags: tools

I am assuming torx key and star tip key are the same thing.

I bought a torx key set from leyland to undo some torx screws on car however they did not work.  Mechanic then used a ratchet with torx extensions and it did unscrew.

I’m assuming the ones I bought from leyland were not designed for cars but maybe bikes or wardrobes etc.

I was going to buy another torx key set from an auto parts store( https://www.eurocarparts.com/p/am-tech-9pc-l-type-torx-key-553980720?type=shopping&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIvYvhhPjH6wIVB-ztCh0iPQFuEAQYAiABEgIMKPD_BwE) however they are awfully cheap like the leyland product.  I note that torx set at Halfords is 4 times the price.

1. Why didn’t they leyland ones work?
2. Will the linked item be ok for cars or do I need to get the expensive one from Halfords? What’s different about the keys that it will work for car or not.

Note this is not a shopping questions more about how to know I am getting an automotive torx key I.e do I base it on price or how can I know since the leyland one didnt work.

Comment: A regular Torx bit is a Torx bit (obvious exception of the safety/security version, which you rarely run into ... this has a small pin in the center). There aren't ones made for vehicles versus a bike, or what have you. If the fastener you are looking to remove uses a Torx bit, any make of Torx bit should work.

Comment: Buy cheap tools = use once (or not even) then throw away, why serious users spend good money on **good** tools.

Comment: @SolarMike - If you are being facetious, it's not coming through in text.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 no, I was stating a fact, cheap tools break, or worse round off fasteners making subsequent work much harder and/or more expensive. Mind you those “monday morning” jobs were always lucrative, sorting the errors made by weekend “mechanics”...

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 and I am still using quality tools I purchased over 40 years ago - paid good money for them: a good investment.

Comment: OP do these Torx fasteners have a bump in the middle?

Comment: @SolarMike - And I'm using both the "good money" tools and the cheap tools I bought over the last 35 years. Tools don't have to be expensive to work well, they just have to work well.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - I believe the issue was his T20 bit was too big and the T15 was too small.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 That's surprising. The T-sizes overlap so closely that I just use a T20 to drive T25 screws...

Comment: @harper - reinstate Monica no they do not.  They have a hole in the center though.

Answer (score 1):

It is not unheard of that some cheap Torx bits did not fit. Get yourself some quality tools. They are expensive, but worth it. I always enjoy the feeling when I have one of my "good tools" in my hands.

Cheap tools often do not match the heads and are not as strong as the good ones. The poor dimensional accuracy can lead to rounded heads and slipping of the tool, thereby ruining the bolt, your hand and your entire day.