# What type of screw is this, How to remove this screw?

Tags: tools

When trying to remove this screw I used a torx key set however it did not work.  Mechanic thenused his own extension on a ratchet and it did work.

From the comment in this answer [How to ensure I am buying an torx key for automotive repair?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/79540/how-to-ensure-i-am-buying-an-torx-key-for-automotive-repair).  it seems the mechanic may have used a different extension then the torx set I was using.

Is this the case and if so what type of extension might I need.  Note that the leyland torx set definitely did not work in fact you can see I damaged the wired screw by using the leyland one.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a Torx type to me.

Comment: Looks like a T20 or T25
Maybe the set you used was 5 Star and not 6.

Comment: What's the vehicle and where are those screws?

Comment: Civic coupe vti 99. Passenger footwell picture is right of where right foot of passenger would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Honda Civic 1996-2000 Service Manual](https://archive.org/details/HondaCivic19962000/page/n1813/mode/2up) on archive.org they are Torx T30 bolts.

[image]

The two things I can think of is that either:

1. you didn't use the right sized bit (least likely)
2. your tool didn't have a good clearance in that space so you ended up trying to fit it angled in the bolt head; torx don't like that (more likely)

Try undoing the easiest screw first, fit the tool straight and push it all the way into the screw.

Comment: Allen wrenches will not do it.