# Which end of the torx key should I be using?

Tags: tools

I previously asked this question [What type of screw is this, How to remove this screw?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/79541/what-type-of-screw-is-this-how-to-remove-this-screw)

and somebody pointed out it was a t30 torx bit.

Here is my t30.  I notice both ends of the key are different as per pic.  Is one end or the other designed for the screw in the pic? A torx extension on a ratchet will only have one end why do my keys have two and the non circle star seems to be bigger.

[image]

Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I gather it doesn’t fit . Try this https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/T30-Torx-6-Point-Star-Bit-25mm-For-use-with-star-drive-fixings-/282066909964

Comment: Those are not Torx wrenches.

Comment: @blacksmith37 are you referring to the item tony strewart has linked or are you referring to the pictures I have posted in my original question? Even if they are not attachable to wrenches provided they have torx ends they should still work?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use the end that fits.
If it is a security fastener with a “pin” then use the end with the hole, if no pin then either end will do.

But do make sure it is the correct size, ie it has to fit tightly, a smaller one can “touch” the lobes but with too much gap will round out the fastener. Common sense should be applied.

Comment: When you say if it is not a security fastener use either end, as I mentioned both ends look different in size and shape slightly.  The one with the hole looks smaller.  How could either end be ok if they are different in size/shape? I’m assuming your advice to use something that fits refers to using different torx keys atogether rather the two points on the same key?  Thanks

Comment: The end with the hole is a "security" end, a less-common end design. It is used with fasteners that have a pin sticking up from the middle of the recess in the bolt head; this restricts opening to only those users who have the less-common tool. More significantly: as @Blacksmith points out, _these are not Torx tools_. These tools' shapes are different. To unscrew Torx fasteners, as on your car, you need to obtain Torx tools.